# Android Studio open incorrect java class file. Error: "Failed linking the resources."

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

There are more than 10 files are open wrongly in the android studio. When I look forward of that file in the folder and open in notepad then my code is correct. when same file open in the android studio then file contains different code or like (Myworkspace list of URL data - D:/Test Workspace/MyApplcation)

[image]

I do invalid Caches and Restart, rebuild, clean project but nothing went work.
my development is stopped from this point.

Comment: in `MenuItem.class` why didn't complete your code ???

Comment: I successfully code proper code of MenuItem.Class but this class file wrongly open in android studio.

Comment: You try to delete `.gradle` file and remove `offline` mode from `gradle` and. Now **`Clean`** and **`Re-Build`** your project

Comment: Nothing i did with android studio or my project. but yes let me delete .gradle file and reimport this project again.

Comment: Please don't forgot to Unchecked **`Offline`** Mode in android studio

Comment: not working @ali

Comment: Why put resource file in `java` code can you explain me??

Comment: Hi @Ali. this file is auto generate in android studio.  i cant make it resources file as java code. Java file has absolute java code. but this java code file open incorrectly in android studio. and some of java file of my project is correctly open but from that there are more than 5 or 10 files are open incorrectly in android studio. just like in above Image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your file, Select

```
Local History > Show History
```

Now you can see your previous changes,

> Just copy your previous code and paste inside the current file.

Its sad part is that, you have to check all your java files manually and make changes accordingly, else Android Studio won't run your project.

**Or**

If you have your project synced with `git`, you can reset your code using the command:

`git reset --hard HEAD`

In my case, it was resolved by doing this.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Firoz Memon. I tried but not working. now i should have to make a new project.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about this problem your project is absolutely fine do not delete anything just follow the steps mentioned below

1. First close `Android Studio` completely (use `TASK MANAGER`).
2. After that go to the directory where your project is available and copy it then paste 
   in any other drive or folder.
3. Navigate to your project folder --> delete `build` folder.
4. Again navigate to your project folder --> app folder --> again delete `build` folder. 5. Also, Navigate to your project folder --> then open `.idea` folder --> delete 
   `libraries` folder.
5. Now open your `Android Studio` and open your project from the new location.

These steps will solve your problem.

Comment: @MaulikBaraiya If the answer helped you please don't forget to give an upvote :)